# How do you check for a merge in Clearcase?

Tags: merge, clearcase

I'm trying to figure out how to look at a file's merge history in Clearcase. I know it can be done graphically, but I need it returned to stdout.

```
ct lshistory <file>
```

returns the file history, but unless it's specifically commented you don't know what has been merged to what. I basically have three branches: main, int, and dev. I'm trying to determine if there are versions in the dev branch past what has been merged and labeled to the int branch.

Answer (score 0):

This is about finding the merge hyperlinks: see "[How files and directories are merged](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_merge_file_dir.htm)"

[image: merge]

> The `find` and [`lsvtree`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm) `-merge` commands can locate versions with Merge hyperlinks.

The `-merge` option allows to:

> Includes all versions that are at the from-end of one or more merge arrows (hyperlinks of type Merge). Annotations on each such version indicate the corresponding to-objects.

You will find [script examples in that thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=160734), usually about finding versions *not* merged in a branch, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=160734 is a dead link.

Comment: @isakbob Yes, 7 years later, I don't have found a proper replacement yet.