# How to I check if a file is not merged in Clearcase?

Tags: merge, clearcase

## Background

[How do you check for a merge in Clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545198/how-do-you-check-for-a-merge-in-clearcase) talked about method to figure out if a clearcase file is merged with the [`lsvtree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12545715/8981474) method.  However, if one wants to check for its opposite, you can only do this directly through graphical means.  if you enter `ct lsvtree -nmerge` in command line, the following error is returned:

```
cleartool: Error: Some options are not applicable to non-graphical mode.
Usage: lsvtree -graphical [-all] [-nmerge] [-nco]
               [-options pass-through-opts] pname ...
       lsvtree [-nrecurse] [-short] [-all] [-merge] [-nco] [-obsolete]
               [-branch branch-pname] pname ...
```

The error implies my assertion above.

## Question

What is the quickest non-graphical way to see if a clearcase file does not have a merge hyperlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) command should include, as shown in "[Find merge arrows pointing to a version in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14334919/6309)" a:

```
Hyperlinks:
  Merge <- filename@@/main/other_branch/2
```

That is the approach you started to implement [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56634196/6309).

For a single file:

```
cleartool describe aFile | | grep -e "Merge <-"`
```

---

I mentioned in 2013 another approach in "[Find merge arrows pointing to a version in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335333/6309)"

```
cleartool descr -ahlink aFile
# or
cleartool descr -fmt "%[hlink:filter]p" aFile
```