# How do I search for specific kinds of merge hyperlinks in clearcase?

Tags: merge, clearcase

## Background

I have recently created an erroneous merge hyperlink in clear case. This was the result of a script that automerged several files.  Given that a script created the erroneous merge, I am trying to search for other instances of erroneous merge arrows.  Below are the constraints I want to put in my search:

1. All merge hyperlinks created by me.
2. On a specific date

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545198/how-do-you-check-for-a-merge-in-clearcase) talks about finding a merge hyperlink in one file.  However, I am looking for a set of merge hyperlinks that I created.

## What I know

I know that you can [describe hyperlinks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) as shown below:

> Describe a hyperlink.
>
> ```
> cmd-context describe hlink:Merge@516262@/vobs_proj 
> hyperlink "Merge@516262@/vobs_proj"
>  created 2006-07-14T16:43:35 by Bill Bo (bill.user@uranus)
>  Merge@516262@/vobs_proj /vobs_proj/lib/cvt/cvt_cmd.c@@/main/v1.1_port/8 ->
>  /vobs_proj/lib/cvt/cvt_cmd.c@@/main/71
> ```

But I am looking for how to query for the "created..." field from a set of merge hyperlinks.

## Question

How do I query for merge hyperlinks that I created at a specific time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [cleartool find](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.html) to try and link those hlink

```
cleartool find . -kind hlink -user <myLogin>
```

Then try and combine the find with an `exec cleartool describe $CLEARCASE_PN`, maybe adding queries (as described in [the query_language](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm))

If not query is working, at least you could then grep the output for:

- your Login
- excluding (`grep -v`) dates which are too old.

[Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57911088/how-do-i-search-for-specific-kinds-of-merge-hyperlinks-in-clearcase/57911275?noredirect=1#comment102246904_57911275):

> I've found that you can use this to get the hlink names, but you have to use `$CLEARCASE_PN`.
>
> Parsing it is non-trivial because the "`hlink`" formatting property apparently doesn't work.
>
> You would have to:
>
> 1. Filter the output by date (`cleartool desc -fmt "%d %Xn\n" $CLEARCASE_PN`)
> 2. Describe each desired link and grep for "`->`"
>      That'll get you the hyperlink source and destination.
> 3. `rmver -xhlink` would let you remove the merge-created versions

Comment: I've found that you can use this to get the hlink names, but you have to use $CLEARCASE_PN. Parsing it is non-trivial because the "hlink" formatting property apparently doesn't work. You would have to:
1. Filter the output by date (cleartool desc -fmt "%d %Xn\n" $CLEARCASE_PN);
2. Describe each desired link and grep for "->"
That'll get you the hyperlink source and destination. rmver -xhlink would let you remove the merge-created versions.

Comment: @BrianCowan Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If this was recent enough, you should be able to use `cleartool lshistory -minor`
I just created a merge hyperlink, and lshist -min -rec on the root of the VOB showed me this.

`--09-12T15:57  Brianc     make hyperlink "Merge" on version "Documents\libatriadb_ldb.txt@@\main\testbr\1"
  "Attached hyperlink "Merge@504@\foobarf"."
--09-12T15:57  Brianc     make hyperlink "Merge" on version "Documents\libatriadb_ldb.txt@@\main\CHECKEDOUT"
  "Attached hyperlink "Merge@504@\foobarf"."`

A little work with the -fmt option and you may be able to get this formatted how you need it.